# Cannot find module '@angular/core/src/metadata/lifecycle_hooks' - primeng/table/table.d.ts

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have got issue of importing primeNG table to my angular project. so i have import the table module to app.module.ts, i have got error.

ERROR in ./node_modules/primeng/components/dropdown/dropdown.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/cdk/scrolling' in 'D:\test angular\primengs\node_modules\primeng\components\dropdown'
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

```
ERROR in node_modules/primeng/components/table/table.d.ts(5,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core/src/metadata/lifecycle_hooks'.
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have found the solution for it. what i have done is Navigate to "/node_modules/primeng/components/table/table.d.ts". and line no 5 have this

```
import { OnDestroy } from '@angular/core/src/metadata/lifecycle_hooks';
```

i have changed to this.

```
import {OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
```

Comment: after that i have got error is 

" ERROR in ./node_modules/primeng/components/dropdown/dropdown.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/cdk/scrolling'"

Comment: i simply install "npm install @angular/cdk" and 

import { ScrollingModule } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling'; to app.module.ts

Comment: After that everything running perfectly. anyway this is issue i had from angular 8.

Comment: Ditto - thanks Raheem. No idea why this worked but it did.

Comment: This fixed my issue too, in various components, guessing the hierarchy has changed for these imported references.

Comment: Never never never touch code in node_modules. This is generated through nom install. Just bring your primeng version the same as your angular one

Answer (score 8):

Make sure that your primeng version is compatible with your angular version.

Comment: this was the issue for me, I had updated to NG8, but still had refs to primeng 6.  Primeng versions should track with NG versions (i.e. for NG8 you need primeng 8)